# Touble with more complex grouping in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am strugling with rebuilding the document in XSLT 1.0.
The input XML looks like this:

```
<Document>
<HEADER>
 <h1>1</h1>
</HEADER>
<SUMMARY>
 <s1>1</s1>
<SUMMARY>
<SUBMISSION>
 <su1>1</su1>
</SUBMISSION>
<TRANSACTION>
 <tr1>1</tr1>
</TRANSACTION>
<TXPRICE>
 <tx1>1</tx1>
</TXPRICE>
<TXPRICE>
 <tx1>2</tx1>
</TXPRICE>
<CHARGEBACK>
 <c1>1</c1>
</CHARGEBACK>
<FOOTER>
 <f1>1</f1>
</FOOTER>
</Document>
```

As You can see it is unstructured. I'd like to transform it into more structured document

```
<HEADER>
 <h1>1</h1>
</HEADER>
<SUMMARY>
 <s1>1</s1>
 <SUBMISSION>
   <su1>1</su1>
   <TRANSACTION>
     <tr1>1</tr1>
     <TXPRICE>
       <tx1>1</tx1>
     </TXPRICE>
     <TXPRICE>
      <tx2>2</tx2>
     </TXPRICE>
   </TRANSACTION>
   <CHARGEBACK>
     <c1>1</c1>
   </CHARGEBACK>
 </SUBMISSION>
<FOOTER>
 <f1>1</f1>
</FOOTER>
<SUMMARY>
```

I have tryied to do this using templates and some of xml template grouping or using for-each but still no luck.

After some tryies I've came to this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   <xsl:template match="/">
    <Structured_Document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/Document/HEADER"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/Document/SUMMARY"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/Document/TRAILER"/>
    </Structured_Document>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Document/HEADER">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Document/SUMMARY">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Document/SUBMISSION[su1/text() = current()/s1/text()]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Document/SUBMISSION">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Document/TRANSACTN[tr1/text() = current()/su1/text()]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Document/CHARGEBACK[ch1/text() = current()/tr1/text()]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Document/TRANSACTN">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Document/TXNPRICING[tx1/text() = current()/tr1/text()]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Document/TXNPRICING">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Document/CHARGEBACK">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Document/FOOTER">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works, it rebuilds document but the problem is that this idea is very unefficient. Fo 200 lines it is quite ok in processing speed, but not for 15k lines.
I am trying to do this more based on Document structure than for-each and trying to match elements. Yes, I know this will not match TXPRICE/tr2 element but in real example I have fields to match.

Comment: Would is your best effort so far?

Comment: I don't see any grouping in the given example; it seems like a simple matter of moving some nodes into others. In any case, you should ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you. -- Note that the result you show is an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document (no single root element). And what happened to the `FOOTER` element?

Comment: I've added some changes to the first ticket.